# Geopackage from maptiler in geoserver

Tags: geoserver, geopackage, maptiler

I'm faced those days with geoserver.

I have an .gpkg file created by maptiler and want to create a layer on geoserver.  The geoserver version was 2.16 and the geopackage  mosaic is integrated on this version. 
( GeoPackage (mosaic) - GeoPackage mosaic plugin)

I have created the store and when I want to create layer generate below error:

```
Sorry, something unexpected happened on the server.

The GeoServer user list might help you address this issue. Click here to subscribe, and then include in your message the GeoServer version, the stack trace below and the steps to reproduce the problem.
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Method onRequest of interface org.apache.wicket.behavior.IBehaviorListener targeted at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1@12492f5 on component [AjaxLink [Component id = link]] threw an exception at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:268) at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.invoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:241) at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:248) at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:234) at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895) at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64) at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265) at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222) at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203) at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:137) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:177) at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:890) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:26) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:69) at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:73) at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:66) at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:41) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:37) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:320) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127) at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70) at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:51) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:122) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70) at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:70) at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:52) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74) at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1132) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2527) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2516) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.wicket.RequestListenerInterface.internalInvoke(RequestListenerInterface.java:258) ... 113 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:423) at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$9.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:312) at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:47) at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:85) at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:155) at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:601) ... 118 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.getImageLayout(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:1189) at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.getImageLayout(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:445) at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.getImageLayout(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:181) at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.getCoverageSampleDimensions(CatalogBuilder.java:1168) at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverageInternal(CatalogBuilder.java:1030) at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:951) at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:900) at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:410) ... 123 more 
An error occurred while loading the page    ​
```

Comment: Please add some details about your geopackage, which tables are present, where and how are your images stored.

Comment: Hi Ian, I have store may image as  GeoPackage (mosaic) in geoserver. the data are raster file.